# Write Frobenius norm from product of traces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $X, Y$ two matrices. I am trying to write the following in terms of the Frobenius norm
$$
\text{vec}(X)^\top \text{vec}(Y)\text{vec}(Y)^\top\text{vec}(X).
$$

It should be a generalization of the case

$$
\|X\|^2_F = \text{vec}(X)^\top \text{vec}(X)
$$

But I don't know how to write it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Apprentice What does the expression $vec(Y)vec(X)$ mean to you? Pairwise multiplication?

Comment: @pax sorry there was an error. I fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text{vec}(X)^T \text{vec}(Y)^T \text{vec}(Y) \text{vec}(X) = \text{vec}(X)^T\lVert Y\rVert_F^2\text{vec}(X)
= \lVert Y\rVert_F^2 \text{vec}(X)^T\text{vec}(X)
= \lVert Y\rVert_F^2 \lVert X\rVert_F^2$$